# Objective-C String handling issue

Tags: objective-c, json, nsstring, nsarray

I'm trying to read from a JSON response something like below

```
{ 
"URL": 
  { 
     "target": "www.google.com", 
    "0": [ 92, 15 ], 
    "1": [ 92, 16 ], 
    "2": [ 74, 15 ], 
    "4": [ 5, 16 ] 
  } 
}
```

Using SBJSON I've managed to get 'target' field,

```
testString = [[result objectForKey:@"URL"] objectForKey:@"target"];
```

when I do a NSLOG it shows www.google.com

but this piece of code doesn't work for other key pairs.

```
testString = [[result objectForKey:@"URL"] objectForKey:@"0"];
```

and when I try to print testString it gives me an error.

In console I printed values, they were,

```
(lldb) po testString
(NSString *) $4 = 0x0864b190 <__NSArrayM 0x864b190>(
65,
27
)
```

How do I extract these 65 and 27 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is an array of objects. try:

```
NSArray * array = [[result objectForKey:@"URL"] objectForKey:@"0"];
id a = [array objectAtIndex:0]; // 65
id b = [array objectAtIndex:1]; // 27

// now determine the type of objects in the array, and use them appropriately:
if ([a isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
  NSString * string = a;
  ...use appropriately
}
else if ([a isKindOfClass:[NSDecimalNumber class]]) {
  NSDecimalNumber * number = a;
  ...use appropriately
}
...
else {
  assert(0 && "type not supported");
}
```

Comment: I already tried this but it doesn't work for some reason :(  I get an array object, but can't access its values by indexes.

Comment: @Sleepwalkerfx what's the reason, specifically?

Comment: getting this error
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSDecimalNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x865ab70' 
when I run the command `po array' in console it shows an array with 65, and 27 though.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
if([result objectForKey:@"URL"] objectForKey:@"0"] isKindofClass:[NSArray class])
{
   NSArray *arritems = [[result objectForKey:@"URL"] objectForKey:@"0"];
   NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray array];
   for( id *item in arritems)
   {
      if([item is isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
      {
         NSString * valueStr = item; 
         [values addObject:valueStr];
       }
      else if([item is isKindOfClass:[NSDecimalNumber class]])
      {
        NSDecimalNumber * valueNum = item; 
        [values addObject:valueNum];
       }
   } 
   NSLog(@"%@",values);
}
```

Same logic repeat for keys value 1 , 2 , 3

Comment: getting an error in the first line *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9b95890'

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *data = [[result objectForKey:@"URL"] objectForKey:@"0"];
```

Then your items are in `[data objectAtIndex:0]` and `[data objectAtIndex:1]`

Comment: I'm getting this error,
` *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSDecimalNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x865ab70'`

Comment: That's because you're assigning those objects to strings instead of `id`. Get them out as `id`s then simply act based on their type (NSString, NSDecimalNumber, etc...)